# org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer cannot be cast to io.undertow.websockets.jsr.ServerWebSocketContainer

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly-10

I am trying to run spring-boot starter application in wildfly.10.final. source downloaded from [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). I am using intellij idea.

Try 1 : remove spring-boot-starter-web this artifectId from pom file.
Try 2 : adding this configuration to build.gradle

```
configurations {
       compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
 }
```

but both attempts are failed. Can anyone help me ...

Comment: It looks like you probably need to exclude the Tomcat Websocket implementation.

Comment: to do exclude i set the gradle configuration mentioned above was my 2nd try. but i failed to run it on wildfly.

Comment: With the same error message or a different one? If it's the same error message then the Tomcat Websocket implementation is still getting put into your deployment from Gradle.